# Limit number of calls in using Parse

Tags: android, database, many-to-many, realm

I'm building my first application with a backend.

**General info**

The app allows users to upload a place, attach tags to it, pictures, etc.

**Dbs**

I'm using Realm as an offline Db & Parse.com as online Db.

**Example**

I'm building the database model and trying to link all many-to-many relations. An example:
A place has a number of tags (short string), a tag can have a number of places.

To built this I did this with realm:
1. Make the place object
2. For each given tag, make a tag object and add the place object relation
3. Get the place object and add the tag object relation

Now I can get all the tags from one place, when I have the place object.
I can get all the places that belong to a tag object.

I'm building the online version with Parse now, and realised that this approach will lead to many calls.

**Possible solution**

- Don't add the tag object relation to the place relation (step 3)
  instead, query the tag class for relation with place object. (might be very slow?)
- Is there a way to build the model 'offline' and push it as a whole?

*As I'm new to this kind of logic, I hope the question is clear.
I understand it is broad, but I think it is best to explain the total case.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to implement many-to-many relationships in Parse. You can use Arrays or Relations depending on the number of related objects. You can read more in [Parse's documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide#relations-many-to-many).

In Parse Relations, you can add multiple objects in a relation before making a call. Let me take Book and Author example in the documentation and adjust it for your case. The process is:

1. Make the Place object
2. Check if a tag object is exist. Create one if not.
3. Associate the tag objects with place object in a Parse Relation

Here is the code sample:

```
// let’s say we have a few objects representing Place tags
ParseObject tagOne=
ParseObject tagTwo =
ParseObject tagThree =

// now we create a place object or specify the one you want to update
ParseObject place= new ParseObject("Place");

// now let’s associate the tags with the place
// remember to create a "tags" relation on Place
ParseRelation<ParseObject> relation = place.getRelation("tags");
relation.add(tagOne);
relation.add(tagTwo);
relation.add(tagThree);

// now save the book object
book.saveInBackground();
```

---

**EDIT AS COMMENT BELOW**

If you want to find all places with a given tag, you can do like:

```
ParseObject tag = ....
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Place");
query.whereEqualTo("tags",tag);
```

Comment: But then I won't be able to take a tag object and find the places associated. Also checken is the tag exists is a call for each tag?

Comment: You can still do a query to find all places with a given tag. There's an example in the documentation (See my edit above for example). For checking tags, there are several ways too, but I think you can add a field in your Realm database indicate that if the tag is added to Parse yet. It could be a String field with objectId.

Comment: That was part of my question: doing a query to find the places with given tag, will that be better then making the relationship "places" from the tag object?

Comment: What do you think would be more? Number of tags in a place vs. number of places in a tag. My answer is like a guidance to your solution since you are the owner of the project. The choice is yours :)

Comment: Number of places in a tag can be a lot more! So the many to many in 2 directions is not really nescessary? Your guidance is truly helpful and will be rewarded!

Comment: Yes, I think it's not necessary since you can retrieve both ways with query. To be honest, I can't come up with reasons to use many-to-many unless you want to know more about the relationship.